# How to change the Mac OS X Keyboard Layout programmatically?

Tags: macos, qt, keyboard-layout

My Qt app supports changing input language on Linux and Windows. I want to add support for changing the input language in Mac OSX, too.

Unfortunately I don't have any information about the Mac SDK. (My first and last work with OS X was compiling Qt and compiling my app!)

I googling this problem and found that I need to use [Text Input Source Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html) and also I found these codes:

```
TISInputSourceRef isref;
isref = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
CFDataRef uchr = (CFDataRef)TISGetInputSourceProperty(isref, kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData);

UCKeyboardLayout * keyLayoutPtr=(UCKeyboardLayout*)CFDataGetBytePtr(uchr);
```

Is `keyLayoutPtr` a pointer for current keyboard layout?

If the answer to the above question is "yes", then what should I compare with `keyLayoutPtr`?

In other words, how can I check if the current keyboard layout is (for example) "English"? (Or something like `LANG_ENGLISH` in Win API or `us` in XLib.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change OSX keyboard layout("input source") programmatically via terminal or AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729704/change-osx-keyboard-layoutinput-source-programmatically-via-terminal-or-appl)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd pass `isref` to `TISGetInputSourceProperty`, using the key `kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages`, and check whether the first language code in the array is "en" or something like that.  I don't know if it will return just "en" or "en-US" etc.