# Change Keyboard Layout AppleScript Stopped Working After Upgrading to Monterey

Tags: applescript

I have the AppleScript below that worked great in Big Sur. But after upgrading to Monterey, it stopped working. Can anyone help me fix it?

Thanks!

```
changeKeyboardLayout("Squirrel")

on changeKeyboardLayout(layoutName)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "TextInputMenuAgent"
            click menu item layoutName of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
            click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        end tell
    end tell
end changeKeyboardLayout
```

If I change `layoutName` to a number, such as `1`

```
click menu item 1 of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
```

ScriptDebugger shows

```
menu item "U.S." of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "TextInputMenuAgent"
```

[image]

So it is able to get `U.S.`, but the **click** simulation does not have any effects, i.e., it does not switch the keyboard layouts to `U.S.` (from another keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Monterey** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
my changeKeyboardLayoutTo("U.S.")

to changeKeyboardLayoutTo(layoutName)
    ignoring application responses
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of ¬
                application process "TextInputMenuAgent"
    end ignoring
    
    delay 0.1
    do shell script "killall 'System Events'"
    delay 0.2
    
    tell application "System Events"
        launch
        click menu item layoutName of menu 1 of ¬
            menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of ¬
            application process "TextInputMenuAgent"
    end tell
end changeKeyboardLayoutTo
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes one has checked **Show Input menu in menu bar** in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** **Input Sources**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is also coded to workaround the ~5 second delay that is a know issue between actuating the primary *menu* and the the target *menu item* on the *menu*.

See my answer [A: AppleScript - Can't get rid of delay after click](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423354/applescript-cant-get-rid-of-delay-after-click/423440#423440) for the reference to mentioned ~5 second delay, which still persists in **macOS Big Sur** and **macOS Monterey**. It also includes other methods to click the target menu items that can be adapted as/if needed. Although I have not tested the alternate solutions in **macOS Monterey** yet.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Hi @user3439894, thanks. But it doesn't work for me either. I have **Show Input menu in menu bar** checked. It doesn't do anything on my Mac. I was thinking that maybe something was broken during the upgrade (to Monterey).

Comment: @Martin, The _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ shown in my answer does indeed work in **macOS Monterey** as stated. I'm using a clean install of **macOS Monterey** not an upgrade. I'd go into **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** and _toggle the bit_, so to speak, by unchecking/rechecking _applications_ as appropriate to see if that will resolve your issue.

Comment: I had a smc reset and the script is working now. Thanks. The script I posed in the OP used to work with Big Sur, and it did not show the keyboard menu when switching keyboards, nor does it need to `do shell script "killall 'System Events'"`. Do you know why it stopped working in Monterey? Thanks!

Comment: I do not want to see the click menu because it may cause some inconvenience. For example, when I have Alfred activated and switch keyboard layouts, it will cause Alfred to be deactivated.

Comment: @Martin, RE: "Do you know why it stopped working in Monterey? " --  No, sorry. -- RE: "when I have Alfred activated and switch keyboard layouts, it will cause Alfred to be deactivated" -- Can you not just add either e.g. `tell application "Alfred" to activate` or `tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of process "Alfred" to true`

Comment: But I don't always switch keyboard layout when Alfred is activated. I could switch keyboard anytime. Alfred is just one example to show why your solution could interfere with what I might be doing.

Comment: @Martin, Sorry I was assuming you trigger the _keyboard shortcut_ to toggle the **Input menu** with **Alfred**.  BTW I think there may be a _command line utility_ that can change the **Input** _source_. Let me check into it.

Comment: @Martin, Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729704/change-osx-keyboard-layoutinput-source-programmatically-via-terminal-or-appl/63232278#63232278 -- I just compiled the _code_ to an executable and tested it in **macOS Monterey** and it works quite nice and it changed it instantly.

Comment: I saw it. I actually tried it before and also today. It works for some keyboards, but not for all. For example, it does not work for [rime/squirrel](https://github.com/rime/squirrel), even I have put `im.rime.inputmethod.Squirrel` there. Also, some keyboards do not have `Bundle ID` in the `plist` file.