# How to get keyboard layout in Mac OS X with C/C++

Tags: c++, c, macos

I need to get the keyboard layout being used on Mac OS X. I've found old restonces to this but they all are something like this:

[How to change the Mac OS X Keyboard Layout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338781/how-to-change-the-mac-os-x-keyboard-layout-programmatically)

which doesn't work any more. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone is interested, I was finally able to get the keyboard layout with the following code:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
int main() {
    char layout[128];
    memset(layout, '\0', sizeof(layout));
    TISInputSourceRef source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
    // get input source id - kTISPropertyInputSourceID
    // get layout name - kTISPropertyLocalizedName
    CFStringRef layoutID = TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceID);
    CFStringGetCString(layoutID, layout, sizeof(layout), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    printf("%s\n", layout);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

> gcc -o test2 test2.c  -framework Carbon

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

TISInputSourceRef source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
NSString *s = (__bridge NSString *)(TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceID));
```